# Sort collecttion by date DESC using Laravel and Collection

Tags: arrays, laravel, sorting, collections

I have a collection where I am ordering the "total" value in a descending way. When the "total" values are the same, I must order the items by descending date.

```
$collection->sortByDesc('total');
```

To sort the elements by descending date when the totals are equal, I have used `sort` and `sortByDesc` but the elements are still not sorted.

```
//First method
$collection->sortByDesc('created_at')->sortByDesc('total');

//Second method
$collection->->sort(function($a, $b){
   if($a->total === $b->total)
   {
      return strtotime($a->created_at) - strtotime($b->created_at);
   }
})->sortByDesc('total');
```

Neither option works for me and I still have the same result:

[image]

When the result should be the following (items ordered by descent date when the total values are equal):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: It does not help me to sort by "total" and then by "date" since the "total" value is the one that should be a priority.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11#issuecomment-398873250

Comment: Is your date a string/integer or a `Carbon`/`DateTime` object?

Comment: @Namoshek is a Carbon instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sortByDesc` will override the sorting you've done in your `sort` function.

Also, `strtotime($a->created_at) - strtotime($b->created_at)` will order the dates in ascending order not descending order.

The following should give you what you're after:

```
$collection->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->total === $b->total) {
        return strtotime($a->created_at) < strtotime($b->created_at);
    }

    return $a->total < $b->total;
});
```

Lastly, assuming that `created_at` and `updated_at` are `Carbon` instances you shouldn't need to use `strtotime`:

```
$a->created_at < $b->created_at
```

Comment: Thanks for the help friend, now if it works with both order criteria. Greetings and thanks again.